# How to hide context menu in chrome browser view in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome

I would like to hide the context menu( 3 dots) using a chrome browser in Android flutter. Can you check and let me know why below code is not hiding the context menu or let me know how can I remove the default menu items

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyApp'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await widget.browser.open(
                url: Uri.parse(
                    "https://www.google.com/"),
                options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
                  android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                      enableUrlBarHiding: true,
                      instantAppsEnabled: false,
                      addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,
                      toolbarBackgroundColor: Colors.cyan),
                  ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Open MyApp")),
      ),
    );
```